# can I use cookie cutter on a template folder and have another cookiecutter in its sub directory

Tags: jinja2, cookiecutter

I have this file structure:

```
/folder1
   /{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}
       /src
          /{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}{{cookiecutter.package_type}}
               test.py
               main.py
       README.md
       cookiecutter.json
   cookiecutter.json
```

folder1/cookiecutter.json contains:

```
{ 
   project_slug = "project name"
}
```

{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/cookiecutter.json contains:

```
{
  package_type = "regular"
}
```

I want to operate cookiecutter twice first on: project_slug and second time inside {{cookiecutter.project_slug}}

I cannot run cookiecutter on this file structure, is there anyway I can allow it? maybe using hooks.
I just dont know how.

I tried to use this file structure but it looks like cooikecutter expect to have only one template on folder ({{cookiecutter.project_slug}}) and not two, concatenation of two templates ({{cookiecutter.project_slug}}{{cookiecutter.package_type}})

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nested configuration files: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/nested_config_files.html

In your example I it should be something like:

```
{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}/
    ├── regular
    │   ├── cookiecutter.json
    │   ├── {{cookiecutter.project_slug}}
    |       │   ├── ...
    ├── special
    │   ├── cookiecutter.json
    │   ├── {{cookiecutter.project_slug}}
    |       │   ├── ...
    ├── README.md
    └── cookiecutter.json
```

And in your main `cookiecutter.json` file you include:

```
"package type": ["regular (./regular)", "special (./special)"]
```

When you run cookiecutter for your template you will get:

```
[/] Select package type
  1 - regular (./regular)
  2 - special (./special)
```

And only the chosen one will be applied.
It is also fine to have just one option, I added the "special" one just for showcasing.